# Google Sheets - Query: reference cell rather than actual query

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have this query where I have 'hardcoded' the date in it. I need to reference the cell with the date it in and have tried for 2 hours to do this using ampersands,  brackets and a whole range of other stuff. Is this actually possible with this particular query?

So I want it to say: `select D where L='A2'"`

A2 containing: `07-03-2019`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=JOIN(", ", QUERY(A2:L500, "select D where L= date '"&TEXT(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also try

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(D2:D500, L2:L500=A2))
```